# Find area enclosed by parametric curve $x(t)=t^3-3t, y(t)=t^2+t+1$

Tags: calculus

How to find the area of one loop of

$$x(t)=t^3-3t,\>\>\>y=t^2+t+1$$

In Stewart's Calculus there is a formula $\int y(t)x'(t)\,dt$ for parametric curve enclosed with $x$-axis, however, that formula can not compute such region. Need help.

Comment: This curve interesects itself once, so it forms a loop. You have to find the area inside the loop. So the first step is to find the point of intersection and the relevant range of $t$.

Comment: @almagest How to find the intersection by the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find the point where the curve intersects itself.

Suppose the values of the parameter are $s,t$, then comparing the value of $x$, we have $s^3-3s=t^3-3t$ or $(s-t)(s^2+st+t^2-3)=0$. We obviously ignore the solution $s=t$, so $s^2+st+t^2=3$. Similarly, comparing the values of $y$ we get $s^2+s+1=t^2+t+1$, so $s+t=-1$. Squaring and subtracting from the other equation gives $st=-2$, so $s,t$ are the roots of the equation $z^2+z-2=0$ or $(z+2)(z-1)=0$, so $s=1,t=-2$. The point of intersection is $(x,y)=(-2,3)$.

As we move from $t=-\infty$ to $t=+\infty$, the value of $x$ starts at $-\infty$ and ends up at $+\infty$. The stationary points are at $t=\pm1$, corresponding to $x=-2,2$.

So from $t=-2$ to $-1$, $x$ increases from $-2$ to $+2$. Then from $t=-1$ to $t=1$, $x$ decreases back to $-2$. So we want the difference between the area under the curve from $t=-2$ to $-1$ and the area under the curve from $-1$ to $1$.

Can you take it from there? [You say in the question that you know how to calculate the area under a curve given parametrically.]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The key is to find the limits of integration. A "loop" means that the curve intersects itself, so we seek to find two distinct values $t_1$ and $t_2$ such that $(x(t_1),y(t_1)) = (x(t_2),y(t_2))$. This gives us the equations 
\begin{align}
     t_1^3 - 3t_1 &= t_2^3 - 3t_2 \\[3pt]
     t_1^2 + t_1 + 1 &= t_2^2 + t_2 + 1.
\end{align}
Subtracting $\frac{3}{4}$ from both sides of the second equation allows us to complete the square on both sides:
\begin{align}
   t_1^2 + t_1 + \tfrac{1}{4} &= t_2^2 + t_2 + \tfrac{1}{4} \\[4pt]
   (t_1+\tfrac{1}{2})^2 &= (t_2+\tfrac{1}{2})^2.
\end{align}
Taking square roots gives $t_1 + \frac{1}{2} = \pm (t_2 + \frac{1}{2})$. But the solution we seek is $t_1 + \tfrac{1}{2} = -(t_2+\frac{1}{2})$, because the positive solution would give us $t_1 = t_2$, and we want *distinct* $t_1$ and $t_2$. So this gives  $t_2 = -1-t_1$. Now plugging this into the first equation gives
\begin{align}
    t_1^3 - 3t_1 &= (-1-t_1)^3 - 3(-1-t_1) \\[3pt]
     t_1^3 - 3t_1 &= -(1+3t_1+3t_1^2+t_1^3)+3+3t_1 \\[3pt]
     t_1^3 - 3t_1 &= 2 - 3t_1^2-t_1^3. \\[3pt]
     0&= 2t_1^3+3t_1^2-3t_1-2 \\[3pt]
     0&= (t_1-1)(t_1+2)(2t_1+1). 
\end{align}

Hence, $t_1 = 1,-\frac{1}{2},-2$. Plugging each value into $t_2 = -1-t_1$ gives the corresponding $t_2$ values of $1,-\frac{1}{2},-2$. So our solution pairs $(t_1,t_2)$ are $(-2,1),(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2})$, and $(1,-2)$. We disregard $(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2})$ because we want $t_1 \neq t_2$. Note that the first and third pairs are equivalent, but by convention we choose the lower limit of integration to be the smaller number. Hence, $t_1 = -2$ and $t_2 = 1$. Now plugging this into the area formula:
\begin{align}
    \text{Area} = \int_{-2}^{1} (t^2+t+1)(3t^2-3)\,dt.
\end{align}
I leave the remaining work to you. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Reposition the loop with $u=x+2$ and $v=y-3$. Then, along with $s=t-1$, the parametric curve has an easy form

$$u=s^2(s+3),\>\>\>\>\> v=s(s+3)$$

which conveniently shows that loop starts at $s=-3$ and closes at $s=0$ at origin. Thus, the enclosed area is

$$\int_A vdu=\int_{-3}^0 v(s)u'(s)ds = \int_{-3}^0 s^2(s+3)(3s^2+6s)ds=\frac{81}{20}$$